# How to make an option depends on the library version in buildroot

Tags: linux, buildroot

I have an option in the buildroot menu that can be activated only if the version of `MY_LIBRARY` is greater `2.0`.

the library version is configured in the Kconfig file as follow

```
config MY_LIBRARY_VERSION
    string "1.0"
    help
    gives the version of the library
```

The option is configured as follow:

```
config MY_OPTION
    bool " My Option "
    help
    option activated only if MY_LIBRARY_VERSION > 2.0
```

I want add smth that check the version of `MY_LIBRARY` before enabling activation of `MY_OPTION`

Comment: Isn't the answer in your title?  A dependency can be specified by "depends on MY_OPTION".

Comment: @sawdust, Thanks for the reply, as i know if i use depends on MY_LIBRARY`in the configuration of MY_OPTION, this mean MY_OPTION will be visible if MY_LIBRARY is activated, Now if MY_LIBRARY is activated and the version of MY_LIBRARY < 2.0 , MY_OPTION will be visible, which is not expected, MY_OPTION should be visible only if MY_LIBRARY version >2.0

Comment: *"MY_OPTION should be visible only if MY_LIBRARY version >2.0"* -- That may be your goal, but that isn't what you have posted originally.  How is this library version configured?  Typically the version is hardcoded in the package make file.  Only a few items (e.g. kernel, toolchain, busybox) have version selection.

Comment: Maybe I should talk more about how things works in my case, so, using make menuconfig i can choose the library version, and then a script get the version selected and download it from our git repository, since then we have the source files where we can get  the real version of the library. After we can check the version using another script, and it will tell us whether the version is good, this is the bad solution that i don't like,suppose that a user chose a bad version then wait for a long time for his library to be downloaded and by the end he gets informed that  it's a bad version

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in the Kconfig language. Kconfig only supports equality and non-equality conditions.

The workaround is cumbersome. What buildroot does for e.g. the kernel headers version:

- There is a string option to specify the version.
- In addition, there is a choice option to specify all possible versions (`BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_X_Y`).
- There are different, hidden symbols to specify the minimal version (`BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_X_Y`).
- Each `BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_X_Y` option selects the corresponding `BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_X_Y` option.
- Each `BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_X_Y` option selects the previous `BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_X_(Y-1)` option.
- Other config options depend on the `BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_AT_LEAST_X_Y` options.
- In the makefiles, there is a check that the downloaded headers really correspond to the specified `BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_X_Y` option.

A possibly simpler solution for your case would be to allow the user to only choose from a predefined set of versions instead of a free-text string.